# How do I override a sidebar that is registered in a parent theme when using a child theme?

Tags: child-theme, register-sidebar, parent-theme

I currently am using a child theme, and its parent theme has registered sidebars already..

My. problem is that i want to change the parent theme's dynamic sidebar

From:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Footer',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="span3">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h6 style="text-transform: uppercase !important; font-weight:600; !important">',
    'after_title' => '</h6><hr>',
));
```

To:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Footer',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="span3">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h6 class="footer-widget-item">',
    'after_title' => '</h6><hr>',
));
```

Now, how am I supposed to do that? I have found this hook called [after_setup_theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/mew5la) but I'm a bit confused on how to do it. Should I deregister the sidebar then register it again?

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is my attempt but it didn't work:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'parent_override' );
function parent_override() {
    unregister_sidebar('Footer');   
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="span3">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="footer-widgets-item">',
        'after_title' => '</h6><hr>',
    )); 
}
```

Comment: Where is the `register_sidebar()` call in the parent Theme? Is is directly in `functions.php`, or is it inside a callback, hooked into an action with `add_action()`?

Comment: it's called directly in `functions.php`.. just wrapped inside an `if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){ }` clause

Comment: @ChipBennett If it is not hooked into an action then it is impossible?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'parent_override' );
function parent_override() {

    unregister_sidebar('sidebar-4'); 
    /** I have looked for the ID of the sidebar by looking at        
     *  the source code in the admin.. and saw the widget's id="sidebar-4"
     */ 

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="span3">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="footer-widgets-item">',
        'after_title' => '</h6><hr>',
    )); 
}
```

It seems that the id is not a slug of the name, and if you did not specify an id upon registering the sidebar, it will have an id of "sidebar-#"...

Comment: Yep, the Parent Theme is `_doing_it_wrong()` by 1) not putting the `register_sidebar()` call inside a callback hooked into `widgets_init`, and 2) not providing an `ID` for each registered sidebar.

Comment: we bought this theme so, we couldn't change it aotm.. i guess i'll just have to do it this way then..

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'parent_override',11 );
function parent_override() {

    unregister_sidebar('sidebar-4'); 
    /** I have looked for the ID of the sidebar by looking at        
     *  the source code in the admin... 
     *  (look for a string data-widget-area-id="footer-4") 
     *  and saw the widget's id="sidebar-4"
     */ 

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="span3">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="footer-widgets-item">',
        'after_title' => '</h6><hr>',
    )); 
}
```

Comment: Just change add action and By lowering the priority of our action, we ensure that it is called after the parent theme’s functions.php file is loaded.

Comment: Instead of posting the explanation as a comment, just edit to include the explanation in your answer.